# Cannot access variable outside the subscription

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an component in angular. I get data from the API and I instantiate a new object to create a map. But I can't access a variable outside the subscribe function. I also can't access my method.

**maps.service.ts**

This part, get data form api

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MapsService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getMap(params) {
     console.log('Service', params);
     return this.http.get('/api/posts/' + params.id);
    }
}
```

**map.component.ts**
Here, where I build the map with google in the future

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MapsService} from '../maps.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {MapPath} from '../map-path';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-maps',
    templateUrl: './maps.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./maps.component.css']
})

export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {

    results: any;
    params: {};
    test: any;

    constructor(
        private mapsService: MapsService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
        this.params = params;
    });

    this.mapsService.getMap(this.params).subscribe(
        data => {

            this.results = data;
            this.test = new MapPath(data, 'test');
        },
        err => {
            console.log('Error occured', err);
        });

    console.log('this.test', this.test.getX());
    console.log('this.results', this.results);

     }

}
```

**map-path.ts**
Here get the different properties from geoJSON

```
export class MapPath {
    test: string;

    constructor(path: any, test: string) {
        this.test = test;
        console.log('Path', path);
        console.log('test', test);
    }

    getX() {
        return this.test;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Observables are async functions, meaning your subscription callback will happen later than the console.log calls following your `this.mapsService.getMap` call.

This is guaranteed by async nature of Observables.

You can either move your console logs inside of the subscribe function or create another subscription.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how to access method's class outside the subscription ? Like this, I access to my method's only inside...

Comment: You have to wait until data becomes available. Your method will be available, but only once the subscription is processed.

Comment: Without knowing your full specs I cannot help you further. Maybe you can explain what is the use case flow of your application?